# How to plot distributions of two different breeds

Tags: netlogo

I setup two different breeds with the breed command:

```
breed [breeds1 breed1]
breed [breeds2 breed2]
```

and in go, I ask to a random turtle to execute an action command, like this:

```
to go
ask one-of turtles [
   action
  ]
end
```

where `action` is defined as

```
    to action
      ifelse (breed = breeds1) 
      [
        set q random-float 1
        set c q
        set potential_1 (1 + d) * (1 - c)^(d)
      ]
      [
        set c random-float 1
        set potential_2 (1 + (1 / d))*(1 - c)^(1 / d)
      ]
    end
```

For `breeds1`, `q` has value in [0,1] and `c` takes its value. 
For `breeds2`, `q` has value equal to 0 and `c` takes random values in [0,1]. 
Both breeds have `d=3` (fixed value).

`c,q`, and both potentials are global variables. 
What I need to do is to plot the two potentials/distributions.
I used `plotxy` to plot the distributions in the plot code box:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

What I would like are the following two distributions in the same plot. Plot 1 shows the distribution for breeds1, plot 2 for breeds2.

If I consider `potential_1` and `potential_2` as turtles-own (the first one for `breeds1`, the second one for `breeds2`) I receive the message that I can't use `potential_1` in an observer context, because `potential_1` s turtle-only. Same for `potential_2`. 
If I consider `q` and `c` as turtles-own  as following:

```
breeds1-own
[ q
  c
  potential_1
]
breeds2-own
[
  q
  c
  potential_2
]
```

I receive the following error:

> You can't use `c` in an observer context, because `c` is turtle-only

So my question is: how could I plot the two distributions?

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I can't answer your question using your code as I can't work out the logic of the `ask one-of`. So, what I have done instead is created a complete model that does the plotting in the hope that will help you work out what's wrong with your code.

Try this:

```
globals [d]

turtles-own
[ potential
  group
  c
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set d 3
  create-turtles 100
  [ set group one-of ["type1" "type2"]
    action
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to action
  ifelse (group = "type1") 
  [ let q random-float 1
    set c q
    set potential (1 + d) * (1 - c)^(d)
  ]
  [ set c random-float 1
    set potential (1 + (1 / d))*(1 - c)^(1 / d)
  ]
end
```

Then you will need the following as the pens in your plot. You will also need to change the plot settings for each pen to 'point' rather than 'line'.

```
ask turtles with [group = "type1"] [plotxy c potential]
ask turtles with [group = "type2"] [plotxy c potential]
```

What I have done is create 100 turtles in two groups, with the values of the variables 'c' and 'potential' calculated for each group using your code. But it's all done in a single pass - each turtle does its calculation and then control moves to the next turtle as they are created. Then I have each pen in the plot just plot the values from one group.

The error message you were getting "You can't use c in an observer context, because c is turtle-only" means that you tried to use the variable c without letting NetLogo know which turtle's value of 'c' you wanted to use.

Comment: First of all, thank you JenB for your help and answer. I'd have a few questions: 1) as I have two breeds, is it correct to define group only for one? 2) Why would it not work if I considered "breed" instead of "group" in the ifelse condition?

Comment: I haven't tried it but it should work with two breeds. Use `turtles-own` for any variables that they have in common. I just used a single breed as it made the code shorter and the variables are identical so I didn't really need two different ones.

Comment: I think it would be complicated win my code to create a group to split turtles in two breeds. Probably this is my issue with your answer.  I had to create two separate networks with specific characteristics. I thought it could be possible to use breeds instead of groups. But I was wrong

Comment: Do you think it could work if I wrote in go:  `ifelse random-float 1 < 0.5
  [ask one-of breeds1 [action]]
  [ask one-of breeds2 [action]]`? However, my doubt would be on the different equation used for the breeds in `action`. How could I include it?

Comment: (No, it doesn't. I couldn't delete the comment above. I tried to implement it in the meantime but without success)

Comment: Found the solution: I used `ifelse random-float 1 < 0.5
  [ask one-of breeds1 [...]][ask one-of breeds2 [...]]` in go. Then I plotted `ask turtles with [breed = breeds1] [plotxy ... ]`. Same for the other breed. Thank you for your help, JenB